# Set of step function is dense in piecewise functions set, understanding of the statement.

Tags: continuity, riemann-integration, step-function, dense-subspaces

**Note : I think i found the proper mathematical terms that corresponds to what exists in my country , if you notice an obvious error of international term , thanks to correct.**

**Context : Defining Riemann Integral for piecewise functions.**

In most books , i can read the statement as followed :
Let $f$ be a piecewise function on $\left[a,b\right]$.

$\forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists \theta$, a step function on $\left[a,b\right]$, such as $\vert f-\theta\vert\leq \epsilon$

For me , the last part of the sentence means , such as $\forall t\in \left[a,b\right],\vert f(t)-\theta(t)\vert\leq \epsilon $

I'm embarrassed because , for me , a piecewise function can have by definition some indefiniteness points , (on jumps) , as long as the definition that the left and right limit exists is respected.

I imagine we can decide a convention , let's say to define the function on a point of "jump" by the left or the right limit , but then , i guess it should be stated in the theorem.

**Question : How to explain this ambiguity if it's one ?**

Comment: I think the convention on step functions is that they be defined so they are everywhere semi-continuous. Maybe this is explicitly stated somewhere in those books.

Comment: Apostol defines a step function as follows: let $[a, b] $ be a closed interval and a function $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb{R} $ is said to be a step function on $[a, b] $ if there is  partition $P=\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $[a, b] $ such that $f$ is constant on each open interval $(x_{i-1},x_i)$. It does not matter what the values of $f$ are at the end points $x_i$. And for a general interval $I$ we say $f$ is step function on $I$ if there is a closed interval $[a, b] \subseteq I$ such that $f$ is step function on $[a, b] $ and $f$ vanishes at every point of $I\setminus [a, b] $.

Comment: Your post seems to indicate that a piecewise (continuous) function on $[a, b] $ is such that it has a finite number of discontinuities on $[a, b] $ and each discontinuity is a jump (no oscillation, no unbounded nature). The value of function at jumps is totally arbitrary and need not necessarily match the left or right limit. Under this definition the theorem in the post holds.